# Infopath : After a dropdown select it makes a red dashed border around it when an item is selected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a drop down box that reads of a list. It works well but a red-dashed border wraps the box after selection implying it is an incorrect type.
I have checked and I can't see how it is an incorrect type. It is just reading the label and value of a picture file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which value you set as Value in dropdown? Have you check dropdown data type?

Comment: I chose "Title" . Data Type = String.

Comment: Try to set ID field as Value in dropdown and check the result.

Comment: Thank you Viraj. I had forgotten to update this. I had found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution is to change the datafield  type to "choice" and not "lookup" for the dropdown box.